# I am unable select checkbox in dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

It looks like this 
id("ctl05_cbMulti_DropDown")/div[@class="rcbScroll rcbWidth"]/ul[@class="rcbList"]/li[@class="rcbHovered"]/label[1]/input[@class="rcbCheckBox"]

None of these are working

driver. findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[2]")).click();
or 
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_Input")).sendKeys("Smith, John");

Comment: please provide html code of dropdown

Comment: The Question is not clear. Please provide HTML code of dropdown and checkboxes.

Comment: <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;"><input name="ctl05$ctl03$cblUser" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_Input" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
<input name="ctl05$ctl03$cblUser" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_Input" value="" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Sorry, missed this part <div id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Silk " style="width: 248px; display: block; top: 0px; visibility: visible; transition: none;"><div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="height: 46px;"><ul class="rcbList"><li class="rcbItem"><label><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Marvin, Suzanne</label></li><li class="rcbHovered"><label><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Smith, John</label></li></ul></div></div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the requested additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your follow up comment, the problem is that the child selector should be 1 as XPath child selectors are zero based, and the additional parenthesis aren't needed. Just change the number to reference the correct Checkbox, for example:

If you want to select the first Checkbox use this:
Using XPath:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][0]")).click();`

Another way to do get the checkbox is using CSS Selectors:

`driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[class='rcbCheckBox']")[0].click();`

And if you wanted to select the second Checkbox:
Using XPath:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][1]")).click();`

Using CSS:

`driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[class='rcbCheckBox']")[1].click();`

I'm more familiar with CSS so my XPath syntax my not be completely correct. But the idea remains the same.

Comment: Try doing this in your Browser Console Window:

`document.getElementsByClassName('rcbCheckBox')[1]`
What is the output?

Comment: Another option is to try this as well:

`driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('rcbCheckBox')[1].click();");`

It's not the prettiest or cleanest piece of code. But that should click the element successfully.

Comment: I wasn't very clear about the second option. The second option should be used with your selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

I see some mistakes in your first line of code. You should not pass "(" inside xpath.

Correct code should be:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable (By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][2]")));

driver. findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][2]").click();
```

Comment: You've got an extra closing parenthesis that will cause this selector to fail.
Should be `driver. findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox'][2]").click();`

Comment: It seems to be some other element is blocking the UI, you can wait for the element to be available/visible before you try to click on element

Comment: I have updated the code to wait until element is clickable.

Comment: I could not understand. What do you mean by "how to modify this"?

Answer (score 0):

check this example in http://simplejavautomation.blogspot.com/p/dropdown-checkbox.html

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='hida']")).click();

WebElement mutliSelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mutliSelect']"));
mutliSelect.findElements(By.xpath(".//li")).forEach(li -> {
    li.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
});
```